How to find average per day using pivot table?
I have following data that shows distribution of fruits on each date.

I want to achieve the following format via Pivot Table, that shows percentage of Apple on each day and show the average at the end as grand total.

I saw a method in AI, to use helper column that add flags to rows of Apple. But still wasn't able to achieve it.

below are the steps that worked for me-

Select the data
insert pivot table
put Date in the rows
fruits in the column
Count of Fruit in Values
in 'Value field settings', in show values as select % of Row total.

below is an image of what i have done.

